# spectacle-code-slide not highlighting code lines

Tags: reactjs, spectacle

Using the current `spectacle boilerplate (5.2.2)` with  `spectacle-code-slide`, everything works fine until navigating the code inside the CodeSlide element.

```
<CodeSlide
        transition={[]}
        lang="js"
        bgColor="secondary"
        code={require("raw-loader!../assets/code.example")}
        ranges={[
          { loc: [0, 270], title: "Walking through some code" },
          { loc: [0, 1], title: "The Beginning" },
          { loc: [1, 2] },
          { loc: [1, 2], note: "Heres a note!" },
          { loc: [2, 3] },
          { loc: [8, 10] },
        ]}/>
```

Here is the result I'm getting
[image: CodeSlideResult]

Looking at the tutorial from the github of spectacle-code-slide it seems like this is the way to do it (unless I'm making a mistake somewhere) and the way to make Prism (which is used by CodeSlide to do the highlighting) understand the target language is by setting the `lang=""` property.

Here is the question: has anyone manageg to make the CodeSlide component work properly with the current version of spectacle boilerplate ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue currently.

Comment: same issue unfortunately. I can get the code showing and highlighted but it doesn't transition to the lines defined in the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured out how to fix this or not though you need to include some kind of CSS from Prism. [This is the link for the themes](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism-themes). If you add a theme from here to your code, it should work fine. Feel free to add in a different background color though as needed.

Comment: I've included the css and this highlights the code correctly but my issue may be different as I can't transition between the blocks of code defined in the presentation.